# "Input string was not in a correct format." C#

Tags: c#, razor, casting, error-handling, asp.net-webpages

groupID is a number of checkboxes. I am trying to create a comma separated list of UserIDs. GroupIDs identify a group with a number of users as a member. So I have:

```
      string groupIds = Request.Form["groupID"];
        if (groupIds!=null){
            string[] arrayOfGroupIds = groupIds.Split(','); //possible error here if only one checkbox is ticked?
            foreach (string id in arrayOfGroupIds){
                var users = db.Query("SELECT guestID FROM userGroups WHERE id = @0", id);
                foreach(var user in users){
                    userIds += user.guestID + ",";
                }
            }
        }   
        userIds += Request.Form["userId"] + "," + yourID;
```

On my next page I then call :

```
string userIDs = Request.Form["userIDs"];
string[] userIdsArray = userIDs.Split(',');
foreach(string userID in userIdsArray){
if(Convert.ToInt32(userID) == loggedID) { //ERROR HERE
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO Membership(GroupId,UserId) VALUES (@0, @1)", groupID, userID);
    }
```

Which results in the error in the title.

What could be causing this ?

Comment: as a side note,  seriously consider something like Nhiberate or the entityframework, or even linq2sql.

Comment: Are you sure every `userID` in `userIdsArray` is an integer?

Comment: have you tried to debug it by putting a break point at the offending line and see what the userID value is?

Comment: I have added in a breakpoint, after the first page is done with the files, I have "2,,1" in the userIds string, but cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the `userID` in the error line can't convert to an integer. You can add a break point, and see what value the variable actually is, and then modify your code.

BTW, you can convert in a more secure way. Like

```
int userIDInt;
if (int.TryParse(userID, out userIDInt))
{
    if (userIDInt == loggedID)
       // ...
}
else
    // handle the error
```